# How to position a Text/TextSpan inside a class

Tags: flutter, web

How can I position my Text like this? I check the docs and I only see texts that are on each of the other side of the row but not someone like this which is the other way around.

I just wanted to have my first column takes about 30% of the row inside a card with text alignment of right and my second column takes about 70% of the row inside a card with text alignment of left. I also wanted to have it like a sort of table where in everything is in proper alignment with regards to column. Thank you

```
         Date:   Today       
      Address:   Sample       
       Gender:   Male
       Status:   Active
```

Comment: check [Flexible](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Flexible-class.html), more [here](https://itnext.io/flutter-responsive-apps-flexible-vs-expanded-ff8cc92b468f)

Comment: Do you use this information in table?

Comment: @pskink I will check it. Thanks

Comment: @MuhammetÖmer I am planning to use this information on cards within a list

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**You can use this code:**

```
Table(
 children: [
   buildTableRow("Date:", "Today"),
   buildTableRow("Address:", "Sample"),
   buildTableRow("Gender:", "Male"),
   buildTableRow("Status:", "Active"),
 ],
),

TableRow buildTableRow(String _title, String _value) {
 return TableRow(
  children: [
    Container(child: Text(_title), alignment: Alignment.centerRight),
    Container(
      child: Padding(padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 15), child: Text(_value)),
      alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
    ),
  ],
 );
}
```

**Code output:**

[image: Code output]

Comment: Thanks, man. I was wondering if I could do it without relying on table. I was just thinking if it might negatively affect devices with smaller screen.

Comment: @Irvin I don't think there will be a problem if you use Theme TextStyle. Please check this library: https://pub.dev/packages/auto_size_text

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Table class of flutter

https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Table-class.html

```
Table(
    columnWidths: {0 : FractionColumnWidth(.3)},
    defaultVerticalAlignment: TableCellVerticalAlignment.middle,
    children: [

    ]
),
```